# MSBUILD output using C#

Tags: c#, msbuild, error-list

I am trying to build a solution file using C# code using WPF application. Please find the code snippet below:

```
var buildEngine = new Engine();
var project = new Project(buildEngine);
project.Load(<pathToCsProjFile>);
project.SetProperty("Configuration", "Debug");

var success = project.Build();    
if (success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Build Succeeded");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Build Failed");
}
```

When I run the code above, variable "success" holds the value of false. Is there any way to capture the project output and display it in a textblock or any WPF control. I need to see the build errors if any in the application.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way to see all the build errors, you need to implement the [`ILogger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger) interface and pass that instance to the [`Project.Build(ILogger)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234351) method.

For a simple example you can check the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger) example section.

Answer (score 1):

in the build parameters you can provide a logger like this

```
new BuildParameters() 
                {
                    DetailedSummary = true,
                    Loggers = new List<ILogger>(){logger}
                }
```

then you will have to build a custom logger that outputs to a string or a stream so that later you can read it